# Using @Inject Instance<blah> in Spring

Tags: spring, cdi

I know that Instance is not part of JSR 330, but is there a Spring equivalent?  I'm interested in the fact that Instance implements Iterable, so Provider will not be the correct answer.

```
public interface Report { ... }
```

(there are 2 classes implementing Report with `@Named` annotations)

```
@Named
public class ReportRunner {
    @Inject private Instance<Report> reports;
}
```

results in:
No qualifying bean of type [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance] found for dependency...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: AFAIK, you can simply use a `List<Report>`.

Comment: In HK2 there is something called the IterableProvider for cases just like this.  See https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0-b03/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/IterableProvider.html.  But since this question is about Spring this may not be all that helpful.  There is a Spring/HK2 bridge, so you may be able to keep most of your app in Spring and just use the Spring/HK2 bridge for cases like this, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: JB Nizet is correct.  I didn't even know you could do that!  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question out because it has been answered in comments.  As @JB Nizet mentioned above, `List<Report>` works.

For those that wonder what I was doing, it was a generic report runner, wherein each report has its own implementing class, each with a set of DB stored parameters.  With this set up, I can leave the report runner running in my app server, drop in jars as necessary, hit re-scan on the sub-context that the ReportRunner maintains (which scans only the Reporting package) and I can modify reports on the fly, without a server restart.