# CDI - @Any and @Inject

Tags: spring, cdi

Trying to inject bean in a class which has field with @Any annotation. But getting error as -

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.enterprise.inject.Instance' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()}

```
   @Named
@Singleton
public class ProcessorFactoryImpl implements ProcessorFactory {

    @Inject @Any
    private Instance<Processor> processorList;
}
```

Interface is

```
public interface Processor {
some method
}
```

And implementing class is :

```
@Named
@Singleton
@Default
public class ProcessorImpl implements Processor {
}
```

For now, I have only one implementation so did not create qualifiers.

Comment: How is this CDI related? If you use Spring for injection, there is nothing CDI related and certainly not java-ee?

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203489/spring-differences-between-named-and-component

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing Spring DI and CDI which are not made to work together.

Choose one of them but not both.

### If you choose CDI

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ProcessorFactoryImpl implements ProcessorFactory
{  
    @Inject
    private Processor processor;
}
```

and

```
@Dependent
@Default
public class ProcessorImpl implements Processor {
  // etc ...
}
```

In this case, the `processor` attribute is not a List ! You should think about what you expect. If you want a `List<Processor>`, you will have to use a CDI `Producer` instead.

### If you choose Spring DI

```
@Component
public class ProcessorFactoryImpl implements ProcessorFactory
{
    @Inject // or @Autowired
    private Processor processor;
}
```

and

```
@Scope("prototype")
public class ProcessorImpl implements Processor 
{
  // etc ...
}
```

### Mixing Spring and CDI

As written in the comments below, Spring can use `@Inject` and `@Named` as theses annotations are part of JSR-330.

The trouble is that too much framework mixing and using `@Inject` on an `Instance<T>`field cannot be achieved like that with Spring as it is a CDI feature.

To use the same feature, use `@Provider` from Spring.

Example :

#### CDI

```
@Inject
private Instance<MyClass> lazyInstance;
```

usage :

```
MyClasse instance = lazyInstance.get();
```

#### Spring

```
@Inject // or @Autowired
private Provider<MyClass> lazyInstance;
```

usage (same as CDI):

```
 MyClasse instance = lazyInstance.get();
```

Comment: Sure? Reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189531/both-component-and-named-for-the-same-bean-class and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540696/named-annotation-in-spring-mvc it seems spring recognizes CDI annotations as well and  sort of acts as a CDI container.

Comment: Yes you are right : Spring can use `@Inject`, `@Named` , but `Instance<T>` is a pure CDI functionnality. That's why I said that "mixing" frameworks is the issue. The `Instance` class does not belong to JSR-330 neither Spring.

Comment: Ok, clear (I'm not a Spring user) Please add this to the answer, makes it more clear. Maybe also reference the other links I posted. But effectively, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875680/using-inject-instanceblah-in-spring and some other 'duplicates' are already in stackoverflow? Including the answer below by @CassioMazzochiMolin which would better have been a comment to try some of the duplicates... Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `List` instead of `Instance`?

```
@Autowired
private List<Processor> processorList;
```

Comment: tried with List but still getting similar error - Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<com..processor.Processor>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()}

Comment: @javaq You may not need `@Any`. And you also could try `@Autowired` instead on `@Inject`.